# Proof of Feller condition for CIR square root process. Any reference?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, reference-request, proof

Could you please give me some reference for the proof of the so-called Feller condition as to a stochastic differential equation of the form:
$$dr_t=a(b-r_t)dt+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}dB_t\tag{1}$$
with $\left(B_t\right)_{t\geq0}$ denoting a Brownian motion on the filtered probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_n,\mathbb{P}\right)$?

---

I found something [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1756450), but I cannot really understand it, hence I am searching for something alternative. Is there some alternative proof (e.g. from a book)?

Answer (score 6):

It is covered very nicely in Iain Clark's Foreign Exchange Option Pricing, A Practitioner’s Guide (pages 98-104). The book also contains references to the relevant literature including Feller's original paper.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your SDE has an unintended error. It should be:

$$
dr_t = a \cdot (b - r_t) \cdot dt + \sigma \cdot \sqrt{r_t} \cdot dB_t.
$$

On the other hand, the Feller condition is discussed and explained in Section 10.2.1.2 (pg. 432) of the Andersen and Piterbarg book: Interest Rate Modeling.

Hope it helps!

Comment: A silly error of mine, of course, sorry. I have just edited the question. Anyway, I cannot find the proof in your reference, but just a statement of the Feller's condition

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesn't have a full proof there, but the comments are really helpful. It also references Proposition 8.3.1, in Section 8.3 (pg. 319). There, I think it references the paper "Moment explosions in stochastic volatility models"  from Andersen and Piterbarg or the book "Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion" from Revuz and Yor. Thank you!